# Criar um intervalo dentro de um laço for in range()?

Tags: python

Em uma tupla de itens, por exemplo:

```
for x in range(2,numero+1):
```

1) Suponhamos que a variável `numero` já foi definida antes como 7. Dessa forma, como eu faço para não constar o 7 nessa tupla, querendo percorrer todos os itens dela, exceto o 7, usando o método `range` em python?

O que eu coloco dentro do range para satisfazer a condição acima?

```
for x in range():
```

Answer (score 6):

Há várias formas de fazer isso. A mais óbvia é esta:

```
for x in range(2, numero):
    fazer_alguma_coisa()
    fazer_outra_coisa()
```

Se você quiser pular algum número dentro do range, pode fazer isso:

```
for x in range(a, b):
    if x == numero_que_nao_gosto:
        continue
    fazer_alguma_coisa()
    fazer_outra_coisa()
```

Se forem vários números a serem pulados no range:

```
for x in range(a, b):
    if x in numeros_que_nao_gosto:
        continue
    fazer_alguma_coisa()
    fazer_outra_coisa()
```