# Como gerar um intervalo de A até B-1 em Python?

Tags: python

Cá está meu código pra imprimir se um número é primo ou não, porém é necessário que o número impresso pelo usuário não seja constado no bloco `if`, como eu poderia fazer para estabelecer um intervalo no `for in range(2,numero_digitado_pelo_usuario)` para que eu não analise o próprio número digitado pelo usuário no bloco `if` mencionado anteriormente.

```
numero = int(input('Digite seu numero aqui : '))

for x in range(2,numero+1):
        if numero % x != 0 :
                print('primo')
        else :
                print('não primo')
```

Dessa maneira queria achar uma forma de resolucionar esta problemática, obrigado pela solução!

Comment: Noto que a sua pergunta tem bastante relação com a [sua pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/445626/132).

Comment: Seu algoritmo não verifica se o número é primo. As mensagens de seu código estão erradas. Como demonstrou Victor Stafusa você apenas verifica se `numero` é ou não divisível por `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A resposta é `for x in range(2, numero):`.

O primeiro número no `range` é o primeiro valor que é considerado como estando dentro dele. O segundo número é o primeiro que é considerado como estando fora. Então, `range(a, b)` vai de `a` até `b - 1`. Logo `range(2, numero)` vai de `2` até `numero - 1`.

Por exemplo:

```py
numero = 7

for x in range(2, numero):
    if numero % x != 0:
        print(str(numero) + ' não é divisível por ' + str(x))
    else:
        print(str(numero) + ' é divisível por ' + str(x))

numero = 6

for x in range(2, numero):
    if numero % x != 0:
        print(str(numero) + ' não é divisível por ' + str(x))
    else:
        print(str(numero) + ' é divisível por ' + str(x))
```

Gera a seguinte saída:

```
7 não é divisível por 2
7 não é divisível por 3
7 não é divisível por 4
7 não é divisível por 5
7 não é divisível por 6
6 é divisível por 2
6 é divisível por 3
6 não é divisível por 4
6 não é divisível por 5
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](https://ideone.com/ZrgygQ)

Comment: Ainda não funciona,eu quero que o própio número digitado pelo usuário não conste no comando if para assim identificar o número primo, já que eliminei o 1 do comando for e agora quero eliminar o própio número inserido  para que todas as divisões realizadas sejam diferentes de 0 e assim resultar em número primo.

Comment: @kvojps Editei a resposta e mostrei ele rodando quando o número é 7 (ele vai de 2 a 6) e quando ele é 6 (vai de 2 a 5). O teste mostra claramente que o próprio número é excluído sim.

Comment: Muito obrigado meu caro

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você deseja implementar um código que seja capaz de verificar se um determinado número é **primo**.

Segundo a definição, [números primos](https://www.todamateria.com.br/numeros-primos/) são: *números naturais maiores do que 1 que possuem somente dois divisores, ou seja, são divisíveis por 1 e por ele mesmo*.

Uma das forma corretas para verificar se um determinado número é primo, é utilizando o seguinte código:

```
def verifica_primo(n):
    i = 1
    cont = 0
    while i <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            cont += 1
        i += 1
    if cont != 2:
        return False
    else:
        return True


num = int(input('Digite um número inteiro: '))

print(verifica_primo(num))
```

Observe que quando executamos o referido código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite um número inteiro:` . Neste momento devemos digitar um número inteiro e pressionar `enter`. Em seguida, o valor da variável `num` é passado como parâmetro `n` para a função `verifica_primo(n)`. Chegando lá, o bloco `while` percorrerá o intervalo fechado [i, n], onde `i` inicia com o valor `1` indo até o valor máximo `n`. Com ajuda do **1º bloco if** será verificado se `i` é divisor de `n`. Caso positivo, a unidade será acumulada na variável `cont`. Posteriormente, o **2º bloco if** verificará o valor da variável `cont`. Caso seu valor seja **diferente de 2**, a função retornará **False** e, caso contrário, a função retornará **True**. Em outras palavras, se o número digitado for primo, a saída será `True`, caso contrário a saída será `False`.